# How to tell if a dragged element's time is am or pm?

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

When dragging a FullCalendar event, the start and end time is updated as the event is being dragged which is great.

The time, however, is always displayed in 12-hour format, without the am/pm qualifier. So 16:30 is displayed as 4:30, 20:00 is displayed as 8:00, etc. You can see this [in the official demos](https://fullcalendar.io/demos), too.

That means, however, that there is no way to distinguish between am and pm times. In our app, we want to display this time in the timezone of the user.

[The `eventContent` function](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-render-hooks) is called as the event is dragged and it receives a `timeText` argument which I thought I could use for this purpose. However, as already mentioned, this argument does not convey the information about whether the time is before, or after, noon.

Is there any way to get this information from FullCalendar?

Thank you very much.

Comment: You can use the settings to change the time format to whatever you want. Check the documentation.

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventTimeFormat should do the trick for events. There are other settings to control date/time formats in other places, please take a look

Comment: Of course, regardless of the actual display format, you can always log the event's start and end times (which are full Date objects) during eventContent too. Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/XWEwBdR (I've just logged the whole date using its default format but you could easily extract the time portion from it specifically using the standard JS Date functions, and that would not be format-dependent.)

Comment: @ADyson Thank you, so much, I'm not sure how I missed this (probably by not looking hard enough ).